# Algorithm for logarithmically converting a number to a percentage

Tags: math, logarithm

I am looking for a way to convert any number to a percentage in the following way:

1. 1.00 is 50%
2. numbers below 1.00 approach 0% logarithmically
3. numbers above 1.00 approach 100% logarithmically.

   > x > 0. So y needs to approach 0 as x becomes infinitely small on the positive side.

I'm sure this is simple to do, but I can't recall how to do it.

Comment: With infinite limits in either direction?

Comment: Yes - infinite - or at least really big.  But such that the difference between "really big" and "infinite" would be negligible.

Comment: some suggestions here: (a) translate percentages to numbers, e.g. "50%" = 0.5, "100%" = 1.0 -- you can always get back to percentages by multiplying by 100. (b) as Stanislav has pointed out, if you mean "asymptotically" rather than "logarithmically", please edit your question accordingly. (c) Please state the input range for your function clearly. Is it 0 to infinity, or -infinity to +infinity? We are having trouble understanding what it is that you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try `1 / (1 + e^(1-x))`

it's the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) shifted by 1 unit

[image: graph]

If you want it to approach faster, you can change e to something higher

*Edit:*

to have f(0) = 0 you could use `1 - 2^(-x)`

[image: graph]

Comment: Oops -one important point I missed: x > 0.
So y needs to approach 0 as x becomes infinitely small on the positive side.

Comment: Well, given that we've misunderstood you, can you draw a graph of what you want and add it to the question?

Comment: @cobbal: what software are you using? neat graphs!

Comment: default Grapher.app that comes with Mac OS X

Answer (score 4):

When you say logarithmically, do you mean asymptotically?  If so, then "y needs to approach 0 as x becomes infinitely small on the positive side" just means f(0)=0 if f is continuous.  In that case x/(x+1) will work: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F%28x%2B1%29

Comment: assuming the desired behavior for y=f(x) is (a) f(0)=0, (b) f(1)=0.5, and (c) lim x->infinity f(x) = 1, I nominate this answer as the best simple answer. I was trying to think of a function involving just add/subtract/multiply/divide that would work but had a brain cramp.

Answer (score 2):

how about `y = f(t) = 1 - exp(-t/tau)` ?

For t near 0, y is approximately t/tau. For t approaching infinity, y asymptotically approaches 1.

As for the f(1)=0.5 approach, this can be used to solve for tau = 1/log(2).

Answer (score 2):

From what you're describing, I'm hearing the graph of x cubed -- very basic, and should be efficient in most languages.

[Graph http://jedsmith.org/static/S01813305.png](http://jedsmith.org/static/S01813305.png)

This was graphed with `y=(x-1)^3+1` (transforms to make `(1,1)` the origin). You can, of course, make the results a percentage by simply scaling by 50.

You are, ultimately, trying to have an efficient solution to give you a rough percentage behavior in a programming language and not Mathematica, right?

Comment: @Brent: this makes no sense. please reword your question to accurately say what it is you want. The above graph approaches 1 at x=1. You mention in your question you want y to approach 1 as x approaches infinity, and you want y = 0.5 when x = 1.

Comment: Actually, you are right I spoke too soon.  This was not what I was looking for, since Y gets greater than 100

Comment: @Jason: No, he said he wanted a percentage.  I'm giving him the curve, it's up to him what units he wants it in.  The formula that yields the curve is just that, a formula that yields a curve.  He'll have to scale the results, move the origin, etc -- and these are all algebraic transforms.  The input does not have to exactly match the desired output in this case -- he's programming (at least I gathered so from "algorithmically"), not handing in a proof. I got him started, that's all.

Comment: @Brent: What the heck do you mean `y` gets greater than 100? I've given you a curve, it's up to you to scale and manipulate to your desired results. You have not expressed your ranges nor constraints in any sensible fashion, and we're working with the data we are given. Scale the expression and **don't** try to copy and paste it without working with it. I gave you a curve, not a solution.

Comment: @Jed: the "this makes no sense" was referring to Brent's comment, not your answer. Didn't mean to criticize your answer.

Comment: @Jason: Didn't think you were, just getting frustrated because I don't think OP is sure what he's doing and we're all wasting time.